# header() function not working after $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

I have a big issue and I can't solve it. I made a simple login script and it worked on my laptop's LAMP server. I was very happy and i uploaded it to my host, but there i couldn't log in. I solved that header() is not working after $_SESSION. My current test code without any login and everything:

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 $_SESSION['test'] = 10;
 header("Location: anything.php");
 ?>
```

And it doesn't redirect. Where is the problem?

Comment: Can you describe *Not Working* ? What error you getting ?

Comment: Nothing. Just doesn't redirect

Comment: i think its _headers already sent problem_

Comment: But it works fine on my laptop

Comment: Is this the only code in ur php file?? if it is, theres no reason for it not to work.. So I believe theres more, please post entire code.

Comment: No. I created a test code just for this and this also not working :/

Comment: If you view the output source, what do you see? I have a suspicious that the PHP is not being executed at all. Oh also, if you're using UTF8, try UTF8 without BOM.

Comment: Try running it with `error_reporting(-1)` and set `display_errors` to `On`.

Comment: WHERE IS OUR ANSWERS?

Comment: and why I can't post any question?? I just accidentally pushed the button but I am banned:o why?

Comment: And Dear downvoter! Please describe me why did you downvoted my answer? It wasn't answered before and I googled about 2 hours yesterday for the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably that the headers have already been send. That is, `session_start` sends out several HTTP headers. From http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php:

> This function sends out several HTTP headers depending on the
>   configuration. See session_cache_limiter() to customize these headers.

Try turning all warnings and errors on (this should give you a warning) with `error_reporting(-1);`. Doing this during development is good practice anyway.

If it's not that, then you must be sending some output before the header. Although, looking at the example code you gave, that's probably not the case.

See [this very nicely answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php) for more information about the problem.

Answer (score -1):

That's the strange. There must be a error before header function. Error before any header call will sent the header to the browser and your php header function will not work. You can try the javascript to redirect.

```
<?php
your_code.....
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>document.location='http://youdomain/anything.php';</script>";
?>
```

Comment: I dont know why down voted for this answer ?

Comment: And nor I do why I am banned from the community..

Comment: Strange things are happening